# React - How to access hook value using Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-hooks, react-context

I have a LessonThemes component I want to access the `color` value using Context. I have a Test component, I want to import the LessonThemes component inside the Test component and access the color value in the Test component using the React Context, but how can I not implement it.

**LessonThemes.jsx**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function LessonThemes() {
    const [color, setColor] = useState(localStorage.getItem("color"));

    const [themes, setThemes] = useState([
        { name: "G", color: "green" },
        { name: "R", color: "red" },
        { name: "B", color: "blue" },
    ])

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("color", color);
    })

    const SideBarPageContent = (SideBarPageContentBackground) => {
        localStorage.setItem('color', SideBarPageContentBackground);
        setColor(SideBarPageContentBackground);
    }

    return (
        <>
            {
                themes.map((theme, index) => {
                    return (
                        <label key={index}>
                            <input
                                onChange={() => SideBarPageContent(theme.color)}
                                type="radio"
                                name="background"
                            />{theme.name}</label>
                    );
                })
            }
        </>
    );
}
```

**Test.jsx**

```
export default function Test(props) {
   return <LessonThemes />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got it correctly, but using Context is not what you should do here.
Context provides a way to share values like these between components without having to explicitly pass a prop through every level of the tree.

I would suggest here to create a variable colors that you will export, import and call when you want (in your code is set up as hooks but it's not used as it).

Something like
**Colors.jsx**

```
export default const colors = () => [
        { name: "G", color: "green" },
        { name: "R", color: "red" },
        { name: "B", color: "blue" },
];
```

and then
**Test.jsx**

```
import {colors} from './Colors';
```

On the other hand, if you want to organize the theme accordingly to the color passed, just pass it as props. Context requires a superior level that here's missing.

**LessonThemes.jsx**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function LessonThemes({color = localStorage.getItem("color")}) {
```

and in **Test.js**

```
export default function Test(props) {
   const color = localStorage.getItem("color") || 'green';
   return <LessonThemes color={color} />
}
```

Comment: I've updated the answer, let me know if the second part fits the need :)

Comment: I liked the second option better :) only I get an error that " 'color' is not defined " inside the Test component

Comment: What kind of logic will set the first color? Is it on user preference? Or it's defined by other variables? color should be populated first with that value, so LessonThemes can work properly.

Comment: No, at first the `color` is not determined, the `color` must be determined by the user

Comment: I would try to add a new variable then before the return, so it will take the color from the user or, if not provided, give a default one.